# Samba CIFS mount only works after SSH connection to samba server

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, samba, cifs

CIFS mount of my remote samba share for some reason unmounts from client in the middle of nowhere and doesn't mount back (log below) until I do an SSH connection from client to server, which, for some reason - fixes everything until random unmount again

```
Status code returned 0xc0000001 NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
 CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -5
 CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
```

At first I thought that it could be DNS or routing issue, (although, server can be traced and pinged both by address and hostname) I added static entry for server in client's hosts but, apparently, no luck there

Problem persists only on a single specific client with default, clean CIFS/Samba installs on CentOS 5.11

Client versions: `samba 3.0.33-3.41.el5_11, cifs-utils 5.9-93.3`

Server: `cifs-utils 2:6.4-1ubuntu1.1, samba 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.31`

Mounted via fstab like this: `//hostname/sharefolder /mnt/mountfolder cifs user=,password=,sec=ntlm 0 0`

Would be grateful for any ideas where to dig from here